# What happens if OCI (Overseas Citizenship of India) is not renewed?

Tags: india

I am reading conflicting information.

1) OCI is lifelong. YET-

2) OCI is needed to be renewed each time passport is renewed before 21. YET-

3) OCI card holder can travel to India with OCI on old passport without renewing it. [enter link description here](http://www.airindia.in/u-sticker-visa-for-oci-card-holders.htm)

Now, if someone under 21 is living in India, who has OCI on old foreign passport, in India gets foreign passport renewed, but does not renew OCI, is that person's stay in India legal or not ?

Comment: This, it turns out, really probably belongs on Travel more than Expats. Somebody who holds OCI may not at all be an expatriate of that country.

Comment: @ouflak but someone with OCI living in India is an expatriate, and is likely to be the child of expatriates or even a double expatriate (i.e., an Indian who naturalized elsewhere and then moved back to India).

Answer (score 1):

As with passports, most nations prefer to have a picture associated with alternate travel documents that reasonably resembles the person using it to travel into the country. This is why there are usually age-5 and age-10 requirements for new passports for many countries like the U.S. and the UK. So it is not that the OCI status will be lost. It's that if a 20-something shows up at India border control and displays an OCI with a picture that is obviously that of a 2-month old baby, then the border control officer  can refuse entry based on the lack of an ability to verify the holder of the OCI. That person ***has OCI***, but they need to renew it with a more current photograph.

Answer (score 1):

Just wanted to add that if you were already 50 yrs age or older when you got your first OCI, then you dont need to renew.